# A journey from Yekaterinburg to Moscow takes 28 hours by train - or "the journey" - or "journeys"?

Tags: articles

Could we use all three following sentences to refer generically to a "typical journey":

> **The** journey from Yekaterinburg to Moscow takes 28 hours by train.
>   **A** journey from Yekaterinburg to Moscow takes 28 hours by train.
>   **Journeys** from Yekaterinburg to Moscow take 28 hours by train.

I want to know whether the use of articles in these three sentences is fully analogous to the use that makes the noun phrase "bull terrier" generic in respectively:

> **The** bull terrier makes an excellent watchdog.
>   **A** bull terrier makes an excellent watchdog.
>   **Bull terriers** make excellent watchdogs.

... or maybe some of my examples "would not work" generically, or would sound awkward.

What I'm interested in is native speakers' comprehension of these sentences.

Comment: Sentences. 1a is the most idiomatic (with no other context); I'd say 2c just shades it, but there's little to choose here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - thank you! Is **2c** the last sentence in the "bull terrier" series? Does it "shade" sentence **1a**? And I'm afraid I don't know the meaning of "to shade" here..

Comment: Sorry. All three of your second set of sentences are in common use, with the third possibly being just the most natural-sounding without other context. The previous two sound more formal.

Comment: The only sentence of the six that stands out for me as marginally unidiomatic is 1b: *A journey from Y to M takes 28 hours by train.*  One could say "A journey from Y to M can be as brief as 4 hours by supersonic jet or as long as 28 hours by train."  By when referring specifically to the train, one expects "The journey".

Comment: That said, "*A journey by train* .... from Y to M..." is not a problem.  It's the placement of "by train" at the end of the sentence that's causing the dissonance with "A" for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The journey from Yekaterinburg to Moscow takes 28 hours by train.

This would probably be said by a railway employee. They know that such journeys take place regularly. In the employee's mind there is an antecedent to the word 'the'. They are thinking, "... the regular journey..."

> A journey from Yekaterinburg to Moscow takes 28 hours by train.

This version is more hypothetical. It has a sense that you are route-planning and there is an uncertainty about whether you will make this journey or not.

> Journeys from Yekaterinburg to Moscow take 28 hours by train.

This is said 'at a distance'. The phrase sounds authoritative but not immediate. You would probably see this in a guide book.

---

> I want to know whether the use of articles in these three sencences is
>   fully analogous to the use that makes the noun phrase "bull terrier"
>   generic ...

I think, yes, there is a parallel with the bulldog sentences.

Answer (score 0):

> **The** bull terrier makes an excellent watchdog.

means the this breed of the various breeds of dog will keep your property safe.  But

> **The** journey from Yekaterinburg to Moscow takes 28 hours by train.

means that it's a 28-hour trip from Екатеринбург to Москва on the train.  No other "breed" of trip is contemplated.

> **A** bull terrier makes an excellent watchdog.

means that picking a bull terrier will likely get you a good watchdog while picking something else, say a chihuahua, won't.

> **A** journey from Yekaterinburg to Moscow takes 28 hours by train.

sounds a bit strange unless there are numerous rail routes between the two cities.  To get the parallel to the bull terrier example, you'd have to say

> **A** train journey from Yekaterinburg to Moscow takes 28 hours.

Implying that a journey by oxcart might take a different number of hours, perhaps fewer.  Note that the usual locution is "train trip," not "train journey."

> **Bull terriers** make excellent watchdogs.

means the same thing as the first example, with the definite article.  Both talk about bull terriers as a class.

**Journeys** from Yekaterinburg to Moscow take 28 hours by train.

sounds odd because all the journeys you're talking about take the same route in the same type of carrier, and now you've said they take the same amount of time.  So, in general, there's only one such journey.  If you want the plural you need more distinguishing detail:

> I took several trips by train this year between Yekaterinburg and
>   Moscow.

I don't think the Ural Express allows dogs, but that's probably not material.

Comment: Hmm why do you believe that "train trip" is the more usual? Google ngrams gives roughly equal incidence with train journey marginally edging out train trip. To me train journey sounds more natural which is why I checked. Further Google ngram research shows that "train journey" is significantly more common in BrE (than "train trip") and somewhat less common (in the last 80 years) in AmE.

Comment: I should have restricted myself to my side of the Atlantic.  Maybe in your oblast, people talk about journeys.  I can't recall a single time anyone has described a train ride with that word.  Perhaps this is because no one here takes the train unless it's to commute.